# C# Registry.GetValue cannot get the correct value

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows, c#-4.0, overflow

In my code, I need to get the time zone of Venezuela from Registry. What I want is the Index value under the key "Venezuela Standard Time". I use the following code to do that, but seems it do not work correctly. The number returned is "-2147483573", but the correct number is "2147483723". could anyone help to figure out what is wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Registry is in Microsoft.Win32. is the error related to that namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 0x8000004B is larger than an integer.  You need to treat it as an unsigned integer.

So:

```
var t = subKey.GetValue("Index");
uint ut = (uint)t;
```

And then take `ut.ToString()`.

Updated example:

```
int t = -2147483573;  // Simulates your call to subKey.GetValue
uint ut = (uint)t;
string s = ut.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The output is 2147483723.

Comment: Hi Jim. I debugged. The variable t has been "-2147483573" when running there.

Comment: Yes, t will be wrong because of the overflow but ut will fix it.

Comment: I tried. t is "-2147483573". throw out Specified cast is not valid.